# No me genera una matriz correcta

Tags: c

Al hacer los ciclos para que me genera la matriz, llega el punto en que al tener que generar la matriz se queda inmóvil, y no pasa de ahí. El código es para un "juego", dentro del código vienen las instrucciones.
Ya he hecho todo el código y si compila y se ejecuta, pero no me genera la matriz después de dar las instrucciones
Que hice mal?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    system("cls");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int Matriz[4][4], Contador1, Contador2, x, y, TomJerryEncontrados, c1, PuntajeJugador1, PuntajeJugador2;
    PuntajeJugador1=0;
    PuntajeJugador2=0;
    TomJerryEncontrados=0;
    char c2[10];
    bool V1, V2, V3;
    V1=false;
    V2=false;
    V3=true;

    char NombreJugador1[30], NombreJugador2[30];

            printf("Introduce el nombre del jugador 1:\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", &NombreJugador1);
            printf("Introduce el nombre del jugador 2:\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", &NombreJugador2);

            system("cls");

            printf("Hola %s y %s ! Bienvenidos al juego Tom y Jerry\n", NombreJugador1, NombreJugador2);
            printf("Las intrucciones del juego son las siguientes:\n\n");
            printf("%s será Tom y %s será Jerry\n", NombreJugador1, NombreJugador2);
            printf("La matriz tendrá escondidas 3 palabras -Tom- y 3 palabras -Jerry- más aparte una palabra -Queso- y otra -Captura-\n");
            printf("Para encontrar las palabras cada jugador debe dar un número de casilla por turnos\n");
            printf("El juego termina cuando todas las casillas estén abiertas\n");
            printf("El ganador será quién acumule más puntos\n");
            printf("Al encontrar la palabra -Tom- serán 10 puntos para Tom y menos 10 puntos para Jerry\n");
            printf("Al encontrar la palabra -Jerry- serán 10 puntos para Jerry y menos 10 puntos para Tom\n");
            printf("Si Tom encuentra la palabra -Captura- ganará 50 puntos y finalizará el juego\n");
            printf("Si Jerry encuentra la palabra -Queso- ganará 50 puntos y finalizará el juego\n");
            printf("Si Tom encuentra la palabra -Queso- perderá 10 puntos\n");
            printf("Si Jerry encuentra la palabra -Captura- perderá 10 puntos\n");
            printf("Si la casilla está vacía los dos perderán 5 puntos\n");
            system("PAUSE");


            //printf("Cargando...");

            Contador1=0;
            while(Contador1<4)
            {
                while(Contador2<4)
                {
                    Matriz[Contador1][Contador2]=0;
                    Contador2++;
                }
            Contador1++;
            }

            Contador1=0;
            while(Contador1<3)
            {
                srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
                c1=rand()%16;
                y=c1/4;
                x=c1-(4*y);
                if (Matriz[x][y]==0)
                {
                    Matriz[x][y]=1;              // 3 Tom
                    Contador1++;
                }
            }
            Contador1=0;
            while(Contador1<3)
            {
                srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
                c1=rand()%16;
                y=c1/4;
                x=c1-(4*y);
                if (Matriz[x][y]==0)
                {
                    Matriz[x][y]=2;              // 3 Jerry
                    Contador1++;
                }
            }
            Contador1=0;
            while(Contador1<1)
            {
                srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
                c1=rand()%16;
                y=c1/4;
                x=c1-(4*y);
                if (Matriz[x][y]==0)
                {
                    Matriz[x][y]=3;              // 1 Queso
                    Contador1++;
                }
            }
            Contador1=0;
            while(Contador1<1)
            {
                srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
                c1=rand()%16;
                y=c1/4;
                x=c1-(4*y);
                if (Matriz[x][y]==0)
                {
                    Matriz[x][y]=4;              // 1 Captura
                    Contador1++;
                }
            }

            system("cls");
            while (TomJerryEncontrados<6)
            {
                printf("Puntaje de %s = %d  || Puntaje de %s = %d \n", NombreJugador1, PuntajeJugador1, NombreJugador2, PuntajeJugador2);
                if (V1==false)
                {
                    if (V2==true)
                    {
                        printf("La casilla ya fue seleccionada anteriormente\n\n");
                        V2==false;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (V3==false)
                        {
                            printf("El número de casilla no es válido\n\n");
                            V3=true;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            printf("Es turno de %s\n\n", NombreJugador1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (V2==true)
                    {
                        printf("La casilla ya fue seleccionada anteriormente\n\n");
                        V2=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (V3==false)
                        {
                            printf("El número de casilla no es válido\n\n");
                            V3=true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("Es turno de %s\n\n", NombreJugador2);
                        }
                    }
                }

            Contador1=0;
            while (Contador1<4)
            {
                Contador2=0;
                while (Contador2<4)
                {
                    switch (Matriz[Contador2][Contador1])
                    {
                        case 0:
                            printf("%d\t", (4*Contador1)+Contador2+1);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            printf("%d\t", (4*Contador1)+Contador2+1);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            printf("%d\t", (4*Contador1)+Contador2+1);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            printf("%d\t", (4*Contador1)+Contador2+1);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            printf("Vacío\t");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            printf("Tom\t");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            printf("Jerry\t");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            printf("Queso\t");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            printf("Captura\t");
                            break;
                    }
                    Contador2++;
                }
                printf("\n");
                Contador1++;
            }

            printf("Selecciona el número de una casilla\n");
            scanf("%s", &c2);
            int c1=atoi(c2);
            c1=c1-1;
            if (c1>=0 && c1<=15)
            {
                y=c1/4;
                x=c1-(4*y);
                switch (Matriz[x][y])
                {
                    case 0:
                        Matriz[x][y]=4;
                        if (V1==true)
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador2=PuntajeJugador2-5;
                            V1=false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador1=PuntajeJugador1-5;
                            V1=true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Matriz[x][y]=5;
                        TomJerryEncontrados++;
                        if (V1==true)
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador2=PuntajeJugador2-10;
                            V1=false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador1=PuntajeJugador1+10;
                            V1=true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Matriz[x][y]=6;
                        if (V1==true)
                        {
                            TomJerryEncontrados++;
                            PuntajeJugador2=PuntajeJugador2+10;
                            V1=false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador1=PuntajeJugador1-10;
                            V1=true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Matriz[x][y]=7;
                        TomJerryEncontrados=7;
                        if (V1==true)
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador2=PuntajeJugador2+50;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador1=PuntajeJugador1-50;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Matriz[x][y]=8;
                        TomJerryEncontrados=8;
                        if (V1==true)
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador2=PuntajeJugador2-50;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PuntajeJugador1=PuntajeJugador1+50;
                        }
                    default:
                        V2=true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                V3=false;
            }
                system("cls");
            }
            system("cls");
            if(TomJerryEncontrados==6)
            {
                printf("Encontraron todos los Tom y Jerry disponibles\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Fin del juego\n");
            }
            if(PuntajeJugador1>PuntajeJugador2)
            {
                printf("El ganador es %s\n", NombreJugador1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("El ganador es %s\n", NombreJugador2);
            }
        getch();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Contador1=0;
while(Contador1<4)
{
  while(Contador2<4)
  {
    Matriz[Contador1][Contador2]=0;
    Contador2++;
  }
  Contador1++;
}
```

Ahí inicializas `Contador1`, correcto, pero... ¿qué pasa con `Contador2`? No la inicializas luego tendrá un valor aleatorio con prácticamente un 50% de posibilidades de ser menor de 4... piensa que -100000000 es menor que 4 pero no es un índice al que te gustaría acceder...

Para evitar este tipo de despistes es preferible, en iteración de rangos, utilizar `for`. Además considera reducir la vida de las variables a lo mínimo imprescindible... reutilizar variables ayuda a que ciertos errores sean dificiles de detectar:

```
for( int Contador1=0; Contador1<4; Contador1++ )
{
  for( int Contador2=0; Contador2<4; Contador2++ )
    Matriz[Contador1][Contador2] = 0;
}
```

Por cierto, para calcular las coordenadas de la tabla usas esto:

```
y=c1/4;
x=c1-(4*y);
```

Cuando podrías aprovechar la operación *módulo*:

```
y=c1/4;
x=c1%4;
```

No solo crea un código más limpio... además es una solución sensiblemente más rápida y la razón es que cuando el procesador calcula la división suele almacenar el resto en algún registro y viceversa, luego poner las dos operaciones juntas puede dar lugar a que el programa reutilice esos valores en vez de calcularlos de nuevo.

Esto se puede comprobar al examinar el ensamblador que se genera con el siguiente código:

```
int func1(int a, int b)
{
  return a/b;
}

int func2(int a, int b)
{
  return a%b;
}

int func3(int a, int b)
{
  return a/b + a%b;
}
```

Que resulta ser el siguiente:

```
func1(int, int):
    mov     eax, edi
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    ret
func2(int, int):
    mov     eax, edi
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    mov     eax, edx
    ret
func3(int, int):
    mov     eax, edi
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    add     eax, edx
    ret
```

Aquí se observa como únicamente se realiza una operación de división en cada función, aunque en la última se hagan, aparentemente dos divisiones (la división en sí misma y la que permite calcular el módulo).

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando <kbd>[aquí](https://godbolt.org/g/q8F4ka)</kbd>